# How to send data from a table generated with a form inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I have a table generated with a **`ng-repeat`** directive.
Each cell can be editable and each row has a submit button.

[image: My table]

The submit button must send only the data of the affected row to the controller instead of sending the complete table. Then the controller will send it to a database. So if my table is huge and has a lot of rows, I prefer to just send one row to the database instead of the complete table.

Most of the time I use **`<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendMyData()">`** to send data from the view to the controller but in this case I have multiple forms (one per each row).

My problem is that I have no idea how to identify each row generated by the **`ng-repeat`**.

I am using AngularJS Material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need forms to do this. I'll demonstrate how to achieve this using sample data:

Controller:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
        { id: 1, name: "Bob" },
        { id: 2, name: "Alice" }
    ];

    $scope.submitPerson = function(person) {
        // do something to person - send to backend etc...
    };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="submitPerson(person)">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

By clicking the submit button within each row - the individual person object will be passed to the `submitPerson` function in your controller where you can send it to the backend or do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below just to submit one row at a time and also change in any number of rows and tick box which rows to be updated at once by clicking Submit ALL button.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('noduesaccountsmodalcontroller',function($scope){
    
    $scope.nodueaccountassets = [{'name':'x'},{'name':'a'},
    {'name':'b'},{'name':'c'},{'name':'d'}];
    
    $scope.init= function(){
        
    };
    $scope.selectedItems =[];
  
    $scope.rowSubmit = function(row){
      $scope.submittedRow = row;
      };
    $scope.submit = function(acc){
        angular.forEach($scope.nodueaccountassets,function(emp){
            if(emp.selected){
                $scope.selectedItems.push(emp.name);
            }
            });
    };
});
```

```html
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  


  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="noduesaccountsmodalcontroller" ng-init="init()">
    
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>received</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueaccountassets track by $index">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="emp.name"/></td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="emp.selected" value="{{emp.name}}" />
            </td>
            <td> <button type="button" value="submit" ng-click="rowSubmit(emp)">Submit</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

        {{selectedItems}}
    
    Submitted row --- {{submittedRow}}
      

              
      <button type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="submit">Submit ALL</button>
  </body>
```